# Integral and Velocity - MIT Calculus problem

Tags: calculus, integration

**PROBLEM:** I can't understand how absolute value of velocity can be negative.

You drove 125 km on a straight road from your home to the border, but had to turn around when you arrive because you have forgotten to bring your passport. You drove 2 hours on the same road back home. Let $v(t)$ be your car's velocity (in km/hour) at time $(t)$ (in hours), and let $x(t)$ be your car's position (in km) at time.

[image]

Let $A > 0$ be the area of the blue region, and $B > 0$ be the area of the pink region. (These are geometric areas, hence positive numbers, not signed areas.)

Which of the following equals  $\int_0^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = ?$

[image]

I chose $1,3,4$ as correct answer but it says $1,3,5$ are the correct options. And this reasoning is given:

We can see that the area under $y = \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert$ between $t = 0$ and $t =4$ is the same as the sum of the areas of the blue and pink regions. Hence $$\int_0^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = A + B $$ But since $$\int_0^2 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = A, \int_2^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = - B $$ Therefore, $$\int_0^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = \int_0^2 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt - \int_2^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt $$

According to my reasoning, since it is an absolute function:

$$\int_2^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = \left\lvert -B \right\rvert = B $$ Therefore, $$\int_0^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt = \int_0^2 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt + \int_2^4 \left\lvert v(t) \right\rvert dt $$

But that is wrong as per MIT answer, I wonder why.

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: Since integrals can be negative, you have to be careful when the integral has f(x) and not |f(x)| if that helps.

Comment: @TomHimler I don't know what you mean. What I can see is |-3| = 3, for any "x",   |x| = |-x| = x. How come in our case |-v| = -v. I was expecting |v| = |-v| = v

Comment: @Arnuld: For any $x$, it is **not** true that $|x|=|-x|=x$ (indeed, $|-1|=|-(-1)|\neq-1$). What *is* true is that $|x|=|-x|$; to get rid of the absolute value, you **must** know the sign of $x$. See the piecewise definition I gave below.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $v(t)$ is negative for $t \in (2,4)$. Therefore we must subtract $$\int_2^4 v(t) dt$$ in order to compute $$\int_0^4 |v(t)| dt = \int_0^2 |v(t)| dt + \int_2^4 |v(t)| dt$$

$$\int_0^4 |v(t)| dt = \int_0^2 v(t) dt - \int_2^4 v(t) dt $$

Comment: I thought an absolute value can never be negative.  Mathematically,   |x| = |-x| = x and generally, V-shape graph of y = |x| is a proof of that even if "x" is negative, "y" is not.   Then how come |v(t)| = -v(t)  ?

Comment: @Arnuld: The absolute value is not negative but is defined as $$|x|=\begin{cases} x&:x\geq0\\-x & :x<0\end{cases}.$$ In the case $x<0$, then $-x>0$.

Comment: @Clayton, I get your "technical" point. Practically speaking, a negative term becomes positive. Then how come absolute value of velocity became negative ?

Comment: @Arnuld: The absolute value didn't *become* negative. The velocity itself **is** negative. So the absolute value will return the negative value of the velocity (consider the graph: the velocity lies **below** the $x$ axis, which means it has negative values).

Comment: @Clayton yes, exactly, since Velocity is negative, it's absolute value must be positive. just like y = |-x| = x